# How to enable java linting in Code Mirror?

Tags: codemirror, monaco-editor, ngx-monaco-editor

We are trying to create a code editor(IDE) in Angular 11. We mainly use java code in it. We need to show lint errors while typing and also beautifier in it. Is there any package or solution already available?